# Global design - font/custom css

Tags: 2019

in our project we would like to change globally some properties such as font, font size. Something to improve design/UI because in current state it doesn't look like a page in 2020. We have found a tool  [bindtuning](https://bindtuning.com/) but it's paid and we have never used it.

Next thing is that we want to make a custom css, I made a solution where you add a webpart to a site where you put css, but there are some sites where we can't add a webparts and we would also like to change css there.

We use sharepoint 2019 on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

Global modifications to sites can be achieved with an SPFx extension - application customiser. There's plenty of info about how to build one in the MS docs, but here is an example of what you are trying to do, I think:

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/